# R - configure: error: provide at least CXX11 compiler support

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

When installing RGDAL 1.6-6, with GDAL2.4.4 installed, I see the following error message, which I am unable to interpret. Working in Centos 7 Docker Image.

```
#8 8.013 * installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
#8 8.028 ** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#8 8.028 ** using staged installation
#8 8.081 configure: R_HOME: /opt/R/4.2.3/lib/R
#8 8.186 configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu11
#8 8.186 configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
#8 8.186 configure: CFLAGS: -g -O2
#8 8.186 configure: CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
#8 8.186 configure: CXXFLAGS: -g -O2
#8 8.187 configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
#8 8.187 configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
#8 8.410 configure: CXX17 is: , CXX17STD is: 
#8 8.410 configure: CXX is:
#8 8.410 configure: C++17 support not available
#8 8.410 configure: rgdal: 1.6-6
#8 8.410 checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
#8 8.412 configure: svn revision: 1201
#8 8.412 checking for gdal-config... /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
#8 8.412 checking gdal-config usability... yes
#8 8.419 configure: GDAL: 2.4.4
#8 8.422 checking C++11 support for GDAL >= 2.3.0... no
#8 8.423 configure: error: provide at least CXX11 compiler support for GDAL >= 2.3.0
#8 8.433 ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
#8 8.433 * removing ‘/opt/R/4.2.3/lib/R/library/rgdal’
```

I've checked what gcc I have installed:

```
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15)
```

Anyone have a clue how to get this to install correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN  mkdir /lambda && \
     chmod 755 -R /lambda  && \
     printf '#!/bin/sh' > /lambda/cxx_flags.sh && \
     printf '\nmkdir -p ~/.R' >> /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     printf '\necho "CC = $(which gcc) -fPIC"    >> ~/.R/Makevars' >> /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     printf '\necho "CXX17 = $(which g++) -fPIC" >> ~/.R/Makevars' >> /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     printf '\necho "CXX17STD = -std=c++17"      >> ~/.R/Makevars' >> /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     printf '\necho "CXX17FLAGS = ${CXX11FLAGS}" >> ~/.R/Makevars' >> /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     chmod +x /lambda/cxx_flags.sh  && \
     /lambda/cxx_flags.sh
```

This loads up the environment variables into `~/.R/Makevars` that rgdal checks for and passes this build step. This is safe to do, since we know we've got the right version of c++ compiler installed.

Hope this is helpful for anyone else stuck in the same hole.